# Laravel export excel

Tags: excel, laravel-5

When I'm follow this instruction:

> http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/getting-started#installation

For exporting an excel document. It says that I've to do this for laravel 5:

> After updating composer, add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in app/config/app.php
>
> 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider',

But all my providers in the providers array have something like this:

> Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,

So should I put this here?

> Illuminate\Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider:class,

that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add following code in `config/app.php`  like this

```
Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
```

in your provider array and

```
'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel:class,
```

to your alias array and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks for helping! in the last one you've to add 2 ::

Comment: adding aliases will make it easier to implement it in your controllers. Instead of writing `use Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider`, you can just write `use Excel`